# Set user's `Service Cloud User` attribute using SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, soap, user

I want to set `Service Cloud User` by making use of the SOAP API's create() or edit() call. The problem is I can't find the attribute's real name. Like all others do have names, for example: 'CommunityNickname'. If I look in the SOAP API Developers Guide I can't even find a reference to the `Service Cloud User` checkbox

[image]

How can I set this attribute using SOAP API?

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

userpermissionsupportuser

It's really weird that I can't find this by searching for Service Cloud User. It's also weird that it's not documented here:
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/apex_api.pdf